# Cannot communicate between arduino and python using pyserial

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I have started a project on arduino where i require it to communicate with python.I have gone through web and found a sample code on arduino python serial communication where,it lights up the LED when 1 is enterd.
Both python and arduino code are working but the  LED is not lighting up.
The board is functioning properly since,i have tried other basic examples

Arduino code:

I

```
  void setup() 
   {
      pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
     digitalWrite(12,LOW);  
     Serial.begin(9600);
 }

  void loop() 
 {
   if(Serial.available() > 0)
   {
     if(Serial.read() == 1)
     {
       digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
       delay(2000);
     }
   }  

     else
     {
       digitalWrite(12,LOW);
     }
     }
```

Python Code:

```
import serial
import time  # Required to use delay functions

arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)  # Create Serial port object called arduinoSerialData
time.sleep(2)  # wait for 2 secounds for the communication to get established


print ("Enter 1 to turn ON LED and 0 to turn OFF LED")

while 1:  # Do this forever

    var =input()  # get input from user
    var=var.encode()


    arduinoSerialData.write(var)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   if(Serial.available() > 0)
   {
     if((char)Serial.read() == '1')
     {
       digitalWrite(12,HIGH);
       delay(2000);
     }
   }
```

And check this [awesome tutorial on arduino forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=396450)